# How to force VSCode to require manual choice where goimports match multiple packages with same name?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, goimports

I just ran into issues where I am writing small web service with Go Iris framework. Iris has few useful packages for HTTP request error handling.

Namely, I wanted to use ***"github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger"*** and
   ***"github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/recover"*** however when I start typing app.Use(logger....) VSCode auto imported "***github.com/hashicorp/consul/logger***" which is also in my path.

Simply copy-pasting right path will solve the issue, but is there a way to force VSCode to make a manual choice where multiple packages names are matched or even fully disable goimports for these cases.

Example below:

```
package main

import (
    // "github.com/hashicorp/consul/logger" ! incorrect package

    "github.com/kataras/iris"
    "github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger"
    "github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/recover"
)

func main() {
    app := iris.New()
    app.Logger().SetLevel("debug")
    // Optionally, add 2 built'n handlers
    // that can recover from any http-related error
    // and log the requests in terminal
    app.Use(recover.New())
    app.Use(logger.New())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start typing in the `import ()` declaration, it will give you suggestions that match. So if you were to type `logger` it would give you the suggestion of:

```
github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger
```

and

```
github.com/hashicorp/consul/logger
```

Just put the `""` in the `import` and start typing the package you want.