# How to display golang package full path in vscode when there are multiple package with same name?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

similar issue with [How to force VSCode to require manual choice where goimports match multiple packages with same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381598/how-to-force-vscode-to-require-manual-choice-where-goimports-match-multiple-pack?newreg=588e09d23d87415d83175c3340c7fc79)

I have two package under different directories
github.com/myproject/mytest1/mytest
github.com/myproject/mytest2/mytest

When I type "mytest", the autocomplete gives me the
[suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e09ly.png) with two "mytest". I can't tell which directory the two "mytest" belong to. Is there a way to display the full path of package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrows to move selection in the autocomple window.
[image: Autocompletion in VS code]

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, when you see the list with choices, press `^ + Space`. That will show the full package path as you move from one package to the other.